# How to set the pre-emptive auth value in header value in adapter implementation file in mobile first 7.1?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using authentication header in the IBM integration bus, so to call the IIB service from mobile first adapter, I am using the following values in adapter.xml file. IIB service is expecting pre-emptive value, so how to set that value in adapter.xml

```
<connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <domain></domain>
            <port>443</port>
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <authentication>
                <basic/>
                <serverIdentity>
                    <username></username>
                    <password></password>
                </serverIdentity>
            </authentication>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->     
        </connectionPolicy>
```

Comment: What value are you attempting to set?

Comment: pre-emptive auth value

Comment: along with basic,username, password in authentication

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "pre-emptive auth value" and where exactly in the XML do you expect to place this, but you can simply place the values for username and password in the available nodes. Are these static or dynamic values for you?

Comment: static only, that I did, but I am not getting the response, this pre-emptive value is mandatory. I tried the same in soap ui, I am getting the response. In soap ui there is option called Authorization and Security related settings, In that settings we want to set the preemptive-auth value as Authenticate preemptively

Comment: Can you give an example of what the expected HTTP request should look like? You assume we know what this IIB auth value but we don't...

Comment: It is the value which we will set in soap UI in Authorization and Security related settings. The key is preemptive-auth, the value is Authenticate preemptively

Comment: how to send the basic authorization with username and password and auth type as basic in adapter impl js file